# Why does safari hide my paragraph text when using after pseudo-element?

Tags: css, safari

When working on a project I wanted to underline a paragraph, but I wanted to style the underlining so I decided to go for an after pseudo-element. This approach proved successful in most browser except for safari, where it renders the pseudo element but doesn't render the text inside te p tags.

Does anyone know what's happening?
You can find the part of my code which's giving me a headache in the following codepen: https://codepen.io/KobeVervoort/pen/KWjaGp

HTML

```
<ul class="toggle">
    <li class="navLink about"><a href="about.php"><p 
class="selected">about</p></a></li>
    <li class="navLink projects"><a href="projects.php"><p>projects</p>
</a></li>
    <li class="navLink contact"><a href="contact.php"><p>contact</p>
</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.selected
{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgb(248, 87, 166), rgb(255, 88, 88));
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.selected::after
{
content: "";
display: block;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgb(248, 87, 166), rgb(255, 88, 88));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `position: absolute;` on the psuedo element instead of `position: relative;` Might have to change the positional values a little afterwards but I believe this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.selected` CSS properties are making the text transparent:

```css
.selected {
  /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgb(248, 87, 166), rgb(255, 88, 88)); */
  /* -webkit-background-clip: text; */
  /* -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; */
}

.selected::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, rgb(248, 87, 166), rgb(255, 88, 88));
}
```

```html
<ul class="toggle">
  <li class="navLink about">
    <a href="about.php">
      <p class="selected">about</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navLink projects">
    <a href="projects.php">
      <p>projects</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="navLink contact">
    <a href="contact.php">
      <p>contact</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```